# Examples of measures that assign positive measure to countable sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a countable (and finite) set of Real-valued $N$-dimensional vectors. The Lebesgue measure of this set $A$, denoted $\lambda(A)$, is just $\lambda(A)=0$ because the Lebesgue measure assigns measure zero to all countable subsets. The Dirac measure of this set $A$, denoted $\delta(A)$, may or may not be zero, since:
\begin{gather}
\delta_x(A)=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }x\in A\\
0&\text{if }x\notin A
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
for some $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. My first question is this: **in case they exist, can you provide examples of other measures that are not the Dirac one, that can be positive for some countable set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?**

**BONUS QUESTION**: consider some (possibly uncountable and infinite) set $B\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ and consider this construction:
\begin{gather}
\delta_B'(A)=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }A\cap B\neq\emptyset\\
0&\text{if }A\cap B=\emptyset
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
My bonus question is as follows: **is the construction $\delta_B'(A)$ a measure? Why or why not?**

**EDIT**: While $\delta_B'$ satisfies the properties of 'non-negativity' and 'null empty set', I think it fails to satisfy 'countable additivity'. Consider two sets $A,A'\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ such that $A\cap A'=\emptyset$ yet $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ and $A'\cap B\neq\emptyset$. Then, $\delta_B'(A)=1$, $\delta_B'(A')=1$ and $\delta_B'(A\cup A')=1$. However, $\delta_B'(A)+\delta_B'(A')=2$, thus implying $\delta_B'(A\cup A')\neq\delta_B'(A)+\delta_B'(A')$ and therefore countable additivity fails to be satisfied. **Is this reasoning correct?**

Comment: First part: $\sum a_n\delta_{x_n}$ with $a_n >0$. Second part:  please try to prove that it is a measure and show your attempt.

Comment: I already edited the question as suggested... Also, when I said 'on top of the Dirac measure' in the first question, I meant 'other than the Dirac measure' rather than 'how to construct the measure relying on the Dirac function'.

Comment: Your argument for the bonus question is correct. If $\mu$ gives non-zero measure to a point $x$ then we can  write $\mu=c\delta_c x+\nu$ for some measuer $\nu$. In this sense we cannot avoid dirac measures for the first question.

Comment: Your question is "**in case they exist, can you provide examples of other measures that are not the Dirac one, that can be positive for some countable set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?**   There are several trivial examples of such  measures. For instance, $\lambda + \delta x$ is not a Dirac measure and it is positive for some countable set.

Comment: @Héctor  Using the Borel (or the Lebesgue) $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^n$, let $\nu_1$ be **any** measure such that $\nu_1 \neq 0$ and, for all $x\in \Bbb R$, $\nu_1(\{x\})=0$. Let $C$ be **any** non-empty countable subset of $\Bbb R$ and let $f: C \rightarrow (0,+\infty]$ be a function. For any measurable set $A$, define $\nu$ by
$$ \nu(A)= \nu_1(A) + \sum_{x\in A\cap C} f(x) $$ 
Then $\nu$ is a measure that is positive for some countable set and $\nu$ is **not** a Dirac measure.

Comment: Indeed, assuming your $\sigma$-algebra is such that all one-point sets are measurable, then every $\sigma$-finite measure that is positive on a countable set is of the form described by @Ramiro.

Comment: I systemically upvote any answer and useful comment I receive simply because of the effort. You got my upvote as soon as you posted it & I later accepted it (this is not the only stackexchange community in which I'm active!). Your answer has been really helpful: thank you.

As of now, I'm just wondering a couple of things: 1. whether the measure you construct is just one example out of many or whether Nate's comment above is correct; 2. where's the mistake in Jacob's (previously accepted) answer (I think he just misunderstood my original question, but I'm not sure...).

Comment: Thanks, for letting me know about the upvote. About your question 1, I will add a remark to my answer with details. About your question 2, I think Jacob just misunderstood that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions is: **in case they exist, can you provide examples of other measures that are not the Dirac one, that can be positive for some countable set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?**

Answer:

Using the Borel (or the Lebesgue) $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^n$, let $\nu_1$ be **any** measure (not signed measure) such that $\nu_1$ is not identically zero and, for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$, $\nu_1(\{x\})=0$.

Let $C$ be **any** non-empty countable subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $f: C \rightarrow (0,+\infty]$ be a function. For any measurable set $A$, define $\nu$ by
$$ \nu(A)= \nu_1(A) + \sum_{x\in A\cap C} f(x) $$

Then $\nu$ is a measure. For all measurable set $A$, $\nu(A)\geqslant 0$ and, for all $E \subseteq C$, if $E \neq \emptyset $ then $E$ is countable and $\nu(E) >0$.  However $\nu$ is **not** a Dirac measure.

**Remark 1**:  The construction of the measure $\nu$ is a general construction. Any measure constructed in this way will a measure positive for some countable subset of $\Bbb R^n$, but not a Dirac measure.

**Remark 2**: We can generalize the answer even further:

Assume your $\sigma$-algebra is such that all one-point sets are measurable.

Let $\nu_1$ be **any** measure (not signed measure) such that, for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$, $\nu_1(\{x\})=0$, $C$ be **any** non-empty countable subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and $f: C \rightarrow (0,+\infty]$ be a function. Then $\nu$ defined by, for all $A$ measurable,

$$ \nu(A)= \nu_1(A) + \sum_{x\in A\cap C} f(x) $$

is a measure that is positive on a countable set. The Dirac measures are just special cases where $\nu_1$ is identically zero and $C$ is an one-point set.

Moreover, in the "reverse direction", given  any any measure $\nu$, such that $\nu$ is positive on a countable set, and  for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$, $\nu(\{x\})<+\infty$, then $\nu$ can be obtained from the above construction with $f: C \rightarrow (0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @Héctor Ther argument is valid in $\Bbb R^n$, without any changed. I have updated the answer to make it clear it is for $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... Can the function $f$ be defined as $f:C\to\mathbb{R}_+$ rather than as you define it in your answer? In the work I'm doing, infinity is somewhat disliked...

Comment: @Héctor $f$ don't need to take the value $\infty$. But to keep the example the most general possible I defined it with counter-domain $(0, +\infty]$.

Comment: Does this sort of measure you constructed receive a particular name in the literature? I’d like to read more about it, but don’t know how to look for it...

Comment: Also, in this measure you constructed, some (actually, many) uncountable sets have non-zero measure, correct?

Comment: @Héctor The measures $\nu$ are the addition of two types of measure. The  measures $\nu_1$  such that, for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$, $\nu_1(\{x\})=0$, are called continuous measure. They are divided into two categories with respect to the Lebesgue measure:  absolutely continuous  and singular continuous.  The part of $\nu$  that comes from $f$  is called  pure-point measure or discrete measures.  The Dirac measures are just a special type of pure-point measures correspondent to just one point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I'm not 100% sure yet, but you may have just unlocked the door to the second chapter of my PhD Thesis...

Comment: @Héctor You are welcome. You may want to read about Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem to deep your knowlege on the subject.

Comment: Thank you --I will do. Also, I've seen by checking your SE profile that you have ample experience in measure theory. Is there any good book you'd recommend on the subject?

Comment: @Héctor , There are many good books on Measure theory. It also depends on the previous knowledge of the the reader and the specific interest.  But, in general, I would mention:  1. Measure Theory: Second Edition, Donald L. Cohn;  2. Measure, Integration & Real Analysis, Sheldon Axler; 3.  Measure Theory, Paul R. Halmos.  The third one is now a little dated, but it is still a very good book.  Another book that may be interesting is Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications 2nd Edition, Gerald B. Folland, but it is sometimes kind of tersed in the proofs.

Comment: Thank you for the useful book references. I've been doing some more research, but I'm not able to understand why $\nu_1$ needs to be "not identically zero". Would you mind providing an intuition of the reason why?

Comment: @Héctor  ,  In **Remark 2** in my answer, I write about the general form (where $\nu_1$ is allowed to be identically zero) and then, in this general form, we have that "The Dirac measures are just special cases where ν1 is identically zero and C is an one-point set".
So, in the specific answer to your question, since you request the example **not** to be a Dirac measure, the condition of $\nu_1$ not being identically zero  is just a simple way to ensure that the final measure $\nu$ is not a Dirac measure.

Comment: **Thank you** for your useful reply. Unfortunately, I have a couple of **additional questions**: 1. Why do we need $\nu_1(\{x\})=0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?; 2. Can the set $C$ be an uncountable set? I guess that the answer to question 2 is 'yes'; but I can't see the reason why we need  $\nu_1(\{x\})=0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Any explanation will be highly welcome.

Comment: OK, I just figured out that the answer to question nº 2 in my comment above is 'no' rather than 'yes', but I still haven't been able to figure out the answer to question nº 1 in my comment above.

Comment: @Héctor 1. To help making the answer clear,  I presented the measure $\nu$ decomposed into two components : a continuous measure ($\nu_1$) and a pure point  measure ($\sum_{x\in A\cap C} f(x)$). 

A measure $\nu_1$ is continuous if, by definition, for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$, $\nu_1(\{x\})=0$. 

2.  In the general case, $C$ can be uncountable. Then, for any $A$ such that $A \cap C$ is uncountable, we will have $\sum_{x\in A\cap C} f(x)= \infty$.

Comment: Once more, **thank you** for your comment. I guess that what I want to know is if all measures that assign a positive measure to some countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the addition of a continuous measure with a pure point measure. I understand from your answer and your comments that this is indeed the case. Correct?

Comment: @Héctor Correct.

Comment: **Thank you** very much, Ramiro. In case you're interested and still want to help, feel free to check this other question regarding measure theory that I've posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052793/can-two-sets-a-a-subset-mathbbrn-have-the-same-measure-but-different-expec

Comment: @Héctor You are welcome. I will take a look in the question.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the question is not properly formulated. I will update it tomorrow to make it understandable. I will let you know once I’ve updated it.

Comment: @Héctor One precision: **Assuming the $\sigma$-algebra is such that all one-point sets are measurable**, then all measures defined in such $\sigma$-algebra that assign a positive measure to some countable subset of Rn are the addition of a continuous measure with a pure point measure.

Comment: @Héctor OK. Let me know when you have updated the other question.

Comment: What if $C$ is countable but infinite? Then, for every $A$ such that $A\cap C$ is infinite, will we also have $\sum_{x\in A\cap C}f(x)=\infty$?

Comment: @Héctor  If $A\cap C$ is countable and infinite, then $\sum_{x\in A\cap C} f(x)$ can be finite or infinite, depending on the values of $f(x)$.

Comment: **Thank you** for your comment. Let $A\cap C$ be countable but infinite. Can you provide an example of a function $f:C\to(0,+\infty]$ such that $\sum_{x\in A\cap C}f(x)<\infty$? If this is asking too much for a comment, let me know and I'll post a new question in the site.

Comment: @Héctor , You are welcome. Think of convergent series. Consider $\Bbb R$ and let $C=\Bbb N$. Let $f:C \rightarrow (0,+\infty]$ be defined as $f(n) = \frac{1}{2^n}$.  For any $A$, $\sum_{x\in A\cap C} f(x) \leqslant 2$.

Comment: **Thank you** for your comment. The reason why you assume the Borel (or Lebesgue) $\sigma$-algebra in your answer is because these are well-known $\sigma$-algebras in which all one-point sets are measurable?

Comment: @Héctor , Two reasons: 1. Your question is about $\Bbb R^n$, and you don't mention any $\sigma$-algebra. Moreover you mention Lebesgue measure. The Borel (or Lebesgue) $\sigma$-algebra are kind of the standard $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb R^n$.  2. Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra are $\sigma$-algebras in which all one-point sets are measurable. My answer remains the same if you replace the Borel (or Lebesgue) $\sigma$-algebra by any $\sigma$-algebra in which all one-point sets are measurable. In fact, **Remark 2** in my answer is already written for any such $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Your analysis of $\delta_B'$ is accurate.

Seperately, measures of the sort you seek do not really exist.  Suppose $C$ is a countable set with $\mu(C)>0$.  Suppose moreover that, for each $x\in C$, the set $\{x\}$ is measurable.  Then, by countable additivity, we must have $\mu=\sum_{x\in C}{\mu(\{x\})\delta_x}$ (as measures on $C$).  So any countably-supported measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ *with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra* is expressible in terms of Dirac masses.

But that caveat about $\sigma$-algebras cannot be removed!  For example, consider the set $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\{0,1\}$, with the $\sigma$-algebra $\{S\times\{0,1\}:S\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^+\}$.  (That is, any measurable set cannot determine the second coordinate.)  Dirac masses aren't measures with respect to this $\sigma$-algebra, so (for example) the measure $$\mu(S\times\{0,1\})=\sum_{s\in S}{2^{-s}}$$ cannot be written in terms of them.

Comment: Attention to the question.  The question is "**in case they exist, can you provide examples of other measures that are not the Dirac one, that can be positive for some countable set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?**   There are several trivial examples of such  measures. For instance, $\lambda + \delta x$ is **not** a Dirac measure and it is positive for some countable set.

Comment: So, I suggest you change the phrase "measures of the sort you seek do not really exist." in your answer. It is actually incorrect, considering the exact wording of the question.

Comment: Could you provide more such examples and / or expand on your comment?

Comment: @Héctor  Using the Borel (or the Lebesgue) $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^n$, let $\nu_1$ be **any** measure such that $\nu_1 \neq 0$ and, for all $x\in \Bbb R$, $\nu_1(\{x\})=0$. Let $C$ be **any** non-empty countable subset of $\Bbb R$ and let $f: C \rightarrow (0,+\infty]$ be a function. For any measurable set $A$, define $\nu$ by
$$ \nu(A)= \nu_1(A) + \sum_{x\in A\cap C} f(x) $$ 
Then $\nu$ is a measure that is positive for some countable set and $\nu$ is **not** a Dirac measure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble understanding it... First, what exactly is $\nu_1$ and what do you mean with $\nu_1\neq0$? Also, the measure you propose is a signed measure, isn't it? Last, what should I do if I have marked a user's reply as accepted and then another user shows that such a reply is wrong? Should I unmark it as accepted? I know this is a meta question, but this is the first time I encounter such a situation...

Comment: @Héctor 1. $\nu_1$ a measure, note a signed measure. 2. $\nu_1 \neq 0$ means that $nu_1$ is not identically zero. 3. The measure $\nu$ is not a signed measure.  4. I posted the comments, with more details, as an answer, you can **change the accepted answer**.